# How can i cancel this shortcut key? option+shift+r : ' ‰ '

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

option+shift+r, this is shortcut key rename file in my IntelliJ 
. But show '‰' sign, how can I cancel it?
[image]

Comment: Seems like a bug in IntelliJ. If it's using a key combination for a command, it should consume it. But it seems like it's leaving it to also be processed as input. You could switch to a keyboard layout that doesn't use Option-Shift-R. If necessary, you can duplicate your usual keyboard and remove that mapping, using [Ukelele](https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele).

Comment: @KenThomases Oh! Thanks. OMG!!! Why didn't I think it was an IDE problem. Thank you so much.